# What was the fix for CVE 2021-31917 ? Is this applicable only for infinispan-server?

Tags: infinispan

There is a CVE reported on infinispan
https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2021-31917

It is marked as fixed after 12.0.0.
I need information for which infinispan module this CVE is applicable ?

Answer (score 3):

The module is `org.infinispan:infinispan-server-rest`